# papaparse not parsing full data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse

I am making a react app which fetches and displays some CSV file data from the public folder. My react container looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Chart from "chart.js";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import * as actions from "../actions"
import * as Papa from 'papaparse'

function mapStateToProps({stats}) {
  return {
    data: stats.data
  }
}

class Stats extends Component {
  fetchCsv(fileName) {
    return fetch(fileName).then(function (response) {
      let reader = response.body.getReader();
      let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

      return reader.read().then(function (result) {
        return decoder.decode(result.value);
      });
    });
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    let PlayerArray = [], BallByBallArray = [], MatchArray = [],
      PlayerMatchArray = [], SeasonArray = [], TeamArray = [];

    let PlayerMatchData = await this.fetchCsv("Player_Match.csv");

    Papa.parse(PlayerMatchData, {
      complete: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        PlayerMatchArray = results.data;
        console.log("entries.length: " + results.data.length);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, actions
)(Stats)
```

This is fetching the content of Player_Match.csv file using the fetchCsv function asynchronously and storing it in PlayerMatchData variable.

Then PlayerMatchData is being parsed by papaparse. The issue is that the *file has 12700 entries* in it and it is only *fetching 3776 entries* in google chrome.

Also, strangely it is fetching *1660 entries in firefox*

Any input will be appreciated. :)

Edit: Link to the data: https://www.kaggle.com/harsha547/indian-premier-league-csv-dataset#Player_Match.csv

Comment: Does `PlayerMatchData` have 12700 elements if you split it by `\n`?

Comment: It has 12700 rows of 5 columns. But it is only showing 3776 rows of 5 columns each. I am also attaching the link of the data in the question.

Comment: `PlayerMatchData` is a string. It does not have rows and columns. You can split it line by line into an array of strings and they you either get the expected 12700 number of rows or you don't. If you do then the problem is indeed somewhere inside `Papa.parse`. If not then the problem is in `fetchCsv`

Comment: Yeah, PlayerMatchData does not have all the data. I am not able to understand why though.

Comment: Because `reader.read()` reads one chunk out of the stream at a time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: Yeah, this must be the problem. Can you tell how can I correct it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I got the answer. As told by @SergiuParaschiv `reader.read()` only reads one chunk of data. So I instead used the `fetch` function to complete the task. There was no issue in the parsing.

```
await fetch("Player_Match.csv")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    PlayerMatchData = text;
    // console.log(text)
  })
```

This will do the task.